# ZF2: Define empty array in XML configuration file

Tags: php, zend-framework2, app-config, configuration-files

I have set up my application to use a module configuration xml, by following [this example](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/zend-framework-2-setting-up-module-config-using-xml-file/).

Now I need to define an empty array for one configuration key. The equivalent php configuration file would be:

```
<?php
return array (
  //...the other configurations
  'sample' => array(
    'empty' => array()
  )
);
```

I can't figure out how to build this in xml.
If I try the following xml the parser returns me an empty string, but I need an empty array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zend-config>
    <!-- ...the other configurations -->
    <sample>
        <empty></empty>
    </sample>
</zend-config>
```

Is there an option where i can force Zend\Config\Factory to return an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
<zend-config>
    <sample>
        <empty/>
    </sample>
</zend-config>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats the solution.